# Prove that there is a first time the function is zero

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and satisfy $f(0) = −1$, $f(1) = 1$. 
Prove that there is a first time at which $ f $ is zero: that is, a number $s \in (0, 1)$ with
$f(s) = 0$ but $f(t) \not= 0$ if $t < s$.

I'm thinking of using the least upper bound property on the set and somehow proving it is $ 0 $ at the value?

Any hints?

Comment: You should use the supremum to come up with a candidate for "the first time at which $f$ is zero". Can you think of such a candidate?

Comment: Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that there is at least one root. Now, can we prove that given this case, the function has at most countably many roots?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh no-one said anything about countably many roots and there's no reason to assume countablity.  Consider $f(x) = 0$ for all $\frac 14 \le x \le \frac 34$ but $f(x) < 0$ for $x < \frac 14$ and $f(x) > 0$ for $x >\frac 34$.  That has uncountably many roots but $x = \frac 14$ is the *least* ("first") $x$ so that $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Somebody asked exactly the same question few hours ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090223/a-function-is-continuous-let-f-0-1-to-mathbb-r-satisfy-f0-%e2%88%921-f/3090227#3090227

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A function is continuous. Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ satisfy $f(0) = −1$, $f(1) = 1$. Prove that there is a first time at which f is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090223/a-function-is-continuous-let-f-0-1-to-mathbb-r-satisfy-f0-%e2%88%921-f)

Comment: @N.S. Damn - if I'd seen that other question and your nice succinct answer to it, I wouldn't have bothered posting my effort on this one! :/

Comment: @fleablood You are correct! I did not see that coming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is no first time. Then, for any $s\in (0,1)$ such that $f(s)=0$ (why do you know that even one such $s$ exists?) there exists $s'<s$ such that $f(s')=0$ as well. We can keep doing this and get a decreasing sequence of points $\{s_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Does this sequence converge? How do convergent sequences behave with continuous functions?

Answer (score 1):

We need the following fact: Since $f$ is continuous, the set $Z(f)=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)=0\}$ is a closed set.

It is non-empty by intermediate value theorem. Then $s=\inf Z(f)=\min Z(f)$ is the first time at which $f$ is zero. It is clear $s\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

For an argument from first principles, try defining
$$
S = \{t \in (0, 1) : f(x) < 0 \text{ for all } x \in [0, t) \}.
$$
By the continuity of $f$ at $0$, $S$ is non-empty. By the continuity of $f$ at $1$, $S$ has an upper bound in $(0, 1)$. So $S$ has a least upper bound, $s \in (0, 1)$. Now prove (i) $s \in S$, (ii) $f(s) \leqslant 0$, (iii) $f(s) \geqslant 0$.

(I hope this is OK. You asked for a "hint", so I've left plenty of details to fill in. It's possible I've fooled myself!)

Answer (score 0):

We know $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in [0,1]$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

So $S = \{x|x \in [0,1]; f(x) = 0\}$ is not an empty set and it is bounded by $0, 1$.  So $a=\inf S$ exists.

What is $f(a)$.

Well $f(a) > 0$ is impossible because $f(0) < 0$ so by IVT there would be an $d; 0 < d < a$ so that $f(0)=0$.  So $d \in S$ but $d < \inf S$ which is impossible.

And $f(a)< 0$ is impossible because $f$ is continuous, and if we let $\epsilon = |f(a)| > 0$ we can find a $\delta > 0$ so the for all $c; a-\delta < c < a+\delta$ is well be true that $|f(c)- f(a)| < \epsilon$.  But that means $f(a) < f(c) < 0$ so $f(c)< 0$ for all such $c$. So if $d \in S$ then $d \ge a+\delta$ and $a + \delta$ is a lower bound of $S$, contradicting that $a = \inf S$.

So $f(a) = 0$ and no other value below is such.